# SPO: Digital Asset Content types in OD4B

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, onedrive-for-business

I'm trying to configure a OD4B so that it is able to host and play media files.  Upon trying to create an asset library  / app, it's not available for me to install.  I have full GA rights across the tenancy.

Additionally, I'm not able to see or select the digital asset content types in the OD4 site content types.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to go to your gear icon and go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Features and enable the Rich Media and Video feature. This will then allow you to create an Asset Library.

Answer (score 0):

I'll mark Eric's post as the right one but I've also realised that I can have the content types added to the site's available ones by activating the Publishing feature.